# declare a constant string with a condition

Tags: objective-c, ios

i have a source file to put all my constants ( `constant.h`) like this :

```
#define MY_URL @"url"
#define SECOND_URL @"url2"
...
```

my problèm is to déclare a constant with a condition like this :

```
if (ipad)
   #define MY_CONSTANT @"ipad"
else
   #define MY_CONSTANT @"iphone"
```

How i can do this please and put it in the `constant.h` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if you support both ipad and iphone, you won't know the device until *runtime*.

if you use a constants header, then you might approach the device specific definitions as follows:

constants.h

```
NSString * MON_CONSTANT();
```

constants.m

```
NSString * MON_CONSTANT() {
  switch (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()) {
    case UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone :
      return @"iphone";
    case UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad :
      return @"ipad";
    default :
      return @"omg";
  }
}
```

Notes:

- i recommend putting your constants someplace other than a constants header. there is usually a location (e.g. class) which which more closely related to the constant.
- not using `#define` for your constants, use the `extern NSString* const` approach instead.

Comment: I know this question is a bit old, but in the .m file; would you just put this code in the init method and then allocate an instance of this class in the corresponding class using these "constants".

Comment: @Spectravideo328 clarify -- this is just a function, not a class.

Answer (score 5):

```
#define MY_CONSTANT ( ipad ? @"ipad" : @"iphone" )
```

or

```
#define MY_CONSTANT ( (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) ? @"ipad" : @"iphone" )
```

Edit: The above is appropriate for a Universal app, where the decision is made in real time. If you want a compile time decision, then I typically use a PreProcessor Macro in the Xcode target of IPAD or IPHONE, even UNIVERSAL (to build 3 ways):

```
#if defined(IPHONE)
#define MY_CONSTANT 4
#elif defined(IPAD)
#define MY_CONSTANT 6
#elif defined (UNIVERSALO)
#define MY_CONSTANT ( ipad ? 6 : 4 )
#endif
```

I find it both tedious to write and tedious to read:

```
(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
```

So I create global BOOL variables and set the value in appDelegate (in initialize), and put an "extern BOOL iPad;" statement in my pch file. In initialize:

```
ipad = (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) ? YES : NO;
```

I know I know, globals are bad etc etc - and yes, if you over use them, but for something like this they are perfect.

Comment: Or, if `ipad` is really a #define itself, use a `#if` statement.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but in reality ipad is a function like this :+ (BOOL)isiPad {
    #ifdef UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM
 return (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad);
    #else
 return NO;
    #endif
}